# Make image ignore color animation in css

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<a href="(link)" target="_blank"><img src="(image source)" title="Click to go to a website!" style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;z-index:999"/></a>
```

and here is my CSS code:

```
a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: underline;
-webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
}

a:hover {
color: #f35626;
}
```

but what I want to do is make that this image (in the HTML code above) not use the CSS code shown above because the CSS is used for other parts of my site. Anyone know how?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by specific image? It's unclear question to me...

Comment: The HTML code I posted before, that is the image, let me rephrase my question.

Comment: if it's not _be counted_, then it maybe too _specific_ ?

Comment: Ok, let me change it, I just want it so that this _specific_ image is not going to use the custom CSS code shown above because that is used for other important code.

Comment: Easy just create a class for your `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a class on your image link and filter it out in your css

```
<a class="imageLink" href="(link)" target="_blank"><img src="(image source)" title="Click to go to a website!" style="position:fixed;top:10px;left:10px;z-index:999"/></a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:not(.imageLink) {
    -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
}

a:hover {
    color: #f35626;
}
```

Comment: nice! glad to help! =)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, but I know you edited this a while ago to the new one, do you still have the old one?

Comment: i don't think i edited this post. there's "edited" link in my post. what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
a img { -webkit-animation: none !important; }
```